# Is there a "gas price oracle" method in Web3j?

Tags: gas, web3j, gas-estimate

I read about the [Gas Price Oracle](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Gas-Price-Oracle) in Geth, but I need to use it outside the Geth client.

Is there something similar in [Web3j](https://web3j.io)?

If not can I call the oracle programatically somehow (in Java)?

Answer (score 1):

Creating such an integration should be possible with web3j 3.4.0 - see the following [pull request](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/pull/398) for details.